# ESP-IDF get stuck at found git when compiling

Tags: git, esp32, esp-idf

I am trying to build esp32 code with esp-idf, I installed the windows version from https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/windows-setup.html, and cd the project, but when either running `idf menuconfig` , or `idf -p COM3 flash monitor`, it throws

```
Running cmake in directory d:\bluecubemodv2\build
Executing "cmake -G Ninja -DPYTHON_DEPS_CHECKED=1 -DESP_PLATFORM=1 -DIDF_TARGET=esp32 -DCCACHE_ENABLE=1 d:\bluecubemodv2"...
-- Found Git: C:/Espressif/tools/idf-git/2.34.2/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.34.1.windows.1")
```

and gets stuck

How to fix this?

Comment: If it's really cmake that is "stalling" here, see if you can modify the call to cmake to add `--verbose` or maybe even `--trace-redirect=<file>` to get more info. ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html))

Comment: Can you go to your esp-idf install folder and run “install.bat esp32” and “export.bat”. Then try again. Check for errors while running.

Comment: @RemyHx they throw error when running them https://imgur.com/a/o2g6mNt (idk why its using devkitpro...)

Comment: Strange. Can you run them in a cmd.exe window? Maybe better to run it as a administrator. And copy paste the whole text, if needed. Point is now too less clues.

Comment: it throws the exact same errors when running the batch installer as admin

Answer (score 0):

In my case, where I had the same problem, this is present only from command prompt and powershell.

I reinstalled IDF with IDE installation enabled and then from the included eclipse works properly.